# C# Sorting alphabetical order a - z and then to aa, ab - zz

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a solution in LINQ but anything helps (C#).

I tried using `Sort()` but its not working for example i have a sample list that contains

```
{"a", "b", "f", "aa", "z", "ac", "ba"}
```

the response I get is:

```
a, aa, ac, b, ba,  f, z
```

and what I want is:

```
a, b, f, z, aa, ac, ba.
```

any idea on a good unit test for this method? just to text that it is getting sorted that way.

Comment: Sort by length, then alphabetically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var data = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "f", "aa", "z", "ac", "ba" };
var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x);
```

Result:

> a, b, f, z, aa, ac, ba

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to actually order an existing list, you likely want to use the [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) series of methods (e.g. [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8), [`OrderByDescending()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.8), [`ThenBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8), [`ThenByDescending()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
var orderedList = yourList.OrderBy(x => x.Length)
                          .ThenBy(x => x);
```

### Example

You can [find a working, interactive example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzCKjp) which would output as follows:

> a,b,f,z,aa,ac,ba

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes both of these methods work.

Comment: Any time! I'm glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 2):

This will sort your List of strings first by Length and then by alphabetical order

```
List<string> sorted = original.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You should've either declared `sorted` as `IOrderedEnumerable<string>` explicitly / implicitly with `var` keyword or add `.ToList();` after `.ThenBy(x => x)` for this solution to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for a different perspective,

```
var yourData = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "f", "aa", "z", "ac", "ba" };
var res = yourData.OrderBy(x => x.Length + x).ToList();
```

> a, b, f, z, aa, ac, ba

...

You can try the following for large values,

```
var yourData = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "f", "aa", "z", "ac", "ba", "asdadasdaaaadafgsdgeraaa", "asdasdsaffasfasdfsadaasda"};
var res = yourData.OrderBy(x => (char)(x.Length+97) + x).ToList();
```

**97 => ASCII code of 'a'**